# What are the means to compute relevance score between question-answer pairs?

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, nlp-question-answering

In information retrieval or question answering system, we use TD-IDF or BM25 to compute the similarity score of question-question pair as the baseline or coarse ranking for deep learning.

In community question answering, we already have the question-answer pairs to collect some statistics info. Without deep learning, could we invent an algorithm like BM25 to compute the relevance score of question-answer pair?

What are some ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without deep learning, could we invent an algorithm like BM25 to
>   compute the relevance score of question-answer pair?

Yes, there are many ways to do it. To make your question a little more directed, let's answer "Which are the possible ways to compute the relevance of question-answer pair without using question answering?"

Some examples and explanations:

- TF-IDF [that you mentioned] is actually a feature extraction technique. With it, you retrieve which words from the context are present/important for each document - with this, you can compare two similarly worded (that's what BM25 does).
- Another technique is to use [PageRank](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank), which is the algorithm used by Google. You can actually attempt to replicate it, since it is not too complex.
- One other way is to use graphs to do it. I did it in my Masters research and you can read my dissertation [here](https://github.com/Sirsirious/dissertation/blob/master/Dissertacao_Tiago_Faceroli_Duque_Graph_Based_Approach_for_QA.pdf).

Aside from that, I'd advise you to check on this papers for other examples of Question-Answering (you can get to question-answer matching easily if you understand the concepts): https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025511003860 and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1319157815000890?via%3Dihub.

Also, keep checking [ACL State of the Art Question Answering Techniques](https://aclweb.org/aclwiki/Question_Answering_(State_of_the_art)) for the most updated results and techniques.